# Visualforce Attachment PDF Upload Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded

Tags: visualforce, attachment

I have done some research and most of the solutions is not working for me. I am trying to upload multiple pdf files, and I right now it doesnt even let me upload a single file due to the Maximum view State. Is there a way of bypassing the stats view and make the size more than 135kb?

Class

```
public with sharing class MultiAttachmentController {
 public Id sobjId {get; set;}
    public String pdfBody{get;set;}
    public List<Document> documents {get;set;}
    public List<Attachment> attachments; 
    public List<Attachment> newAttachments {get; set;}
    public static final Integer NUM_ATTACHMENTS_TO_ADD=5;
 public MultiAttachmentController()
    {
        newAttachments=new List<Attachment>{new Attachment()};
        getAttachments();
         documents = [SELECT Id, Name , Body
                         from Document Where FolderId = '005G0000004gpv9']       
    }  
 public void addMore()
    {

        for (Integer idx=0; idx<NUM_ATTACHMENTS_TO_ADD; idx++)
        {
            newAttachments.add(new Attachment());
        }
    } 
 public void save()
    {

        Test();
}

    public void Test(){
List<String> blst = new List<String>();
//attach file from page
blst.add(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(newAttachments.get(0).Body));

String bodyStr = '["'; 
Integer i = 0;
for(String newSt: blst){
    i++;
     bodyStr += newSt + '"';
     if(i < blst.size())
        bodyStr += ',"';
  }
  bodyStr += ']';

System.debug('bodtest:    ' + bodyStr);
}
```

Component

```
<apex:attribute name="objId" type="String" description="The id of the object to manage attachments for" required="true" assignTo="{!sobjId}"/>
    <apex:form id="attForm">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Upload Attachments">
            <apex:repeat value="{!newAttachments}" var="newAtt">
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="File"/>                         
                        <apex:inputFile value="{!newAtt.body}" filename="{!newAtt.name}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Description"/>                      
                        <apex:inputText value="{!newAtt.Description}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:repeat>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!addMore}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Done" action="{!done}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: Try adding newAttachments.get(0).Body=NULL at end of the test() method

Comment: @VigneshwaranG thanks for the reply, I did this  public void Test(){

    newAttachments.get(0).Body = NULL;
List<String> blst = new List<String>();   and now System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

Comment: @VigneshwaranG I also do have blst.add(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(newAttachments.get(0).Body));

Comment: I would recommend you look into "transient" variables.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I have also done that everywhere

Comment: Can you update your code, then, so future helpers know this?

Comment: Add the code which I mentioned as last line in test() method

Comment: @SebastianKessel I dont knwo what I did but I am getting Null pointer error now, let me fix that first

Comment: @VigneshwaranG I dont knwo what I did but I am getting Null pointer error now, let me fix that first

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reduce view size of the Visual force to monitor view size of the page and checking which areas have view size is exceeding.

You can monitor view state performance through the [View State tab in the development mode footer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_tools_edit_toolbar.htm#pages_tools_edit_toolbar) and take the following actions:

Use the transient keyword in your Apex controllers for variables that aren’t essential for maintaining state and aren’t necessary during page refreshes.

If you notice that a large percentage of your view state comes from objects used in controllers or controller extensions, consider refining your SOQL calls to return only data that's relevant to the Visualforce page.

If your view state is affected by a large component tree, try reducing the number of components your page depends on.

This may help you to reduce the view size of the page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply, I have used transient on every variables that I have before and still samething. Let me do the view state tab